# Merge rows of same values in jasper Repors Detail Band

Tags: jasper-reports

My data contains same value for a particular column.

My requirement is to merge the data rows for that particular column alone in detail band.

Is it possible in jasper reports.

please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

You can make another group, other than `Detail` and set the `Group Expression` to the same field you want.

For example, if I want to group on Country, and show Cities in each country. In "Country" Group Expression. I would write:

```
$F{countryField}
```